# Powershell Command Looping From A Single List File

Tags: powershell, loops

I am looking to set up a list of files on different domains and using curl(which is already installed to my $PATH) to them in the order from the list and naming them based on the domain (such as example.com/file.jpg to example.jpg

Currently, I've tried using Get-Content to contain all the URLS in a single variable, yet it wouldn't run properly through wget.

So far I have the following:

```
$list = ".\list.txt"
$lookup_term = "http"
$urls = (Get-Content $list) -match $lookup_term 
curl $urls
```

with the list.txt as follows:

```
https://example.com/image.jpg
https://example2.com/video.mp4
http://example.net/notavirus.avi
```

I was anticipating getting the files to download properly as a start, yet, it ends up attempting to use one of the URLs as a flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking through the list using foreach object.

For example:

```
$urls | ForEach-Object {
   curl $_
}
```

or

```
foreach ($url in $urls) {
 curl $url
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pipe directly , without using a variable:

```
(Get-Content $list) -match $lookup_term | ForEach-Object { curl $_ -ErrorAction Continue}
```

In some scenarios I would use an try/catch with a small(non-annoying) message (or log file)  to catch the non-working urls without killing the script

```
$urls = (Get-Content $list) -match $lookup_term 

ForEach ($url in $urls) {
    try{
        curl $url
    }
    catch {
        Write-error " cannot access url $url" -ErrorAction Continue
    }
}
```